# why do interactive parts of UITextview require a long press?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

I need to make part of a text interactive, this is a screenshot of what I made so far, which is good, but the problems are

1- it requires a long tap

2- and force me to have the text selectable

any idea about how to solve this?

[image: clickable uilabel]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "text with a link", attributes: nil)
        attributedString.setSubstringAsLink(substring: "link", linkURL: "CUSTOM://WHATEVER")
        let linkAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(), NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor(), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
        textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
        textView.selectable = true
        textView.editable = false
        textView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
    {
        if URL == "CUSTOM://WHATEVER"
        {
            print("????")
        }
        else
        {
            print("!!!!")
        }
        return true
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
}

extension NSMutableAttributedString
{
    public func setSubstringAsLink(substring substring: String, linkURL: String) -> Bool
    {
        let range = self.mutableString.rangeOfString(substring)
        if range.location != NSNotFound
        {
            self.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: linkURL, range: range)
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to solve your specific issues but I guess you are better of subclassing UILabel instead of UITextView. Also, try to not re-invent the wheel, use [TTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) or similar libraries to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem like below,

```
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Press this link text")
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "http://www.google.com", range: NSRange(location: 6, length: 14))

    let linkAttributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greyishBrownColor(),
        NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.greyishBrownColor(),
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue
    ]

    agreementsTextView.delegate = self
    agreementsTextView.attributedText = attributedString
    agreementsTextView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes


    // Delegate Method
    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if URL.absoluteString == "http://www.google.com" || URL.relativePath == "http://www.google.com" {
        print("Tapped")
    }

    return false
}
```

Range might be wrong, this should fix your problem

Comment: this is the same as i did, it also requires a long tap, quick tap don't work.

Comment: don't require a long tap, I use few projects and works without any problem.

Comment: on the simulator it does require a long tap, i mean, a quick tap doesn't work, please tell me about your experience on simulator and on device please?

Comment: sorry, you're right, on the simulator a quick tap doesn't work but on the real device, works. I've just tested

Comment: what kind of device did you use? what iOS? what Xcode did you use?

Comment: if you can confirm that it works on any iOS 7+ powered iOS device and on iPad, then your answer will be accepted, i can't see a reference that mentions this :(